# Count and group by day MySQL query

Tags: mysql

How can i count and group by day in MySQL. My issue is that I'm not using a MySQL time stamp.

I'm saving my date in below format

```
date("F j, Y");
```

So the date will be November 24, 2015, November 25, 2015, November 26, 2015 etc.

Can i keep the format as it is and count and group by day?

Comment: can you show some sample date? it essay to understand what you want @max

Comment: Store dates as dates. There is NO reason not to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is - technically - yes, you can groupy by day and keep this format using mysql's [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert your string to a date type and extract the day part out of it using one of the day related functions.

The question is, why would you do this? You should store the date either in a timestamp or datetime column and format the dates to your specification when you query it using [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. This way you can retrieve the dates in the desired format **and** you retain the ability to easily perform date arithmetic within your sql code.

Comment: Thank. I will test it out. To answer your question why i want to do this, because i made this script some time back and already there are so much of old data with the format above. That is why i don't want to change the format.